# Recreate the console en js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a modified console that have the same functionalities as the real console en js :

here what I am trying to do :

```
export function consoleX (tag, msg){

    if (process.env.REACT_APP_PROFILE === "dev") {
        return console(tag, msg);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use consoleX.log, consoleX.error ect

My function is called as follow :

```
consoleX.log("Hi", "Hello")
```

but this is not working since console(tag, msg) is returning exeption..

Any idea ?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the `console` *object* and the `console.log`, `console.error` etc. *methods*.

Comment: `console` is not a function, it's an object. Are you looking for `console.log`?

Comment: Yes I am looking to immitate the console object

Comment: @taboubim Then you'll have to redirect the methods to `console` methods because you can't extend Console.

Comment: working now :) with export const consoleX = process.env.REACT_APP_PROFILE === "dev" ? console : null;

Comment: It wont work when REACT_APP_PROFILE !== "dev". Then consoleX.log will give you error since consoleX will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to try this one? You would need to change as per your requirement/file, but consumption would remain the same.

`consoleX.log("Hi", "Hello")`

```
var consoleHolder = console;
var consoleX = {}
if(process.env.REACT_APP_PROFILE !== "dev"){
    Object.keys(consoleHolder).forEach(function(key){
        consoleX[key] = function(){};
    })
}else{
    consoleX = consoleHolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestion in the comments I ve tried

```
    export const consoleX = process.env.REACT_APP_PROFILE === "dev" ? console : { 
    log: () => {},
    warn: () => {},
    info: () => {},
    error: () => {},
};
```

And all is working now..

Comment: With the dev profile, sure. Otherwise, it'll throw exceptions.